# Wifi preferences

Tags: mac, wifi, macbook-pro

whenever my computer (which is a MacBook Pro bought in 2012) is sleeping or off, and i login with my password, it is always on a different wifi then my home wifi. My home wifi is Skritty, and the wifi my computer is always on is BronzeMaple-Guest. I just waited 10 minutes for a software update and when it turned on, it went to the BronzeMaple-Guest login website and it totally lost my software update. I was trying to play MineCraft and had to update Java so i could play it. IF YOU HELP I WILL BE VERY THANKFUL!

sincerely, Braden

Answer (score 2):

Click on "advanced" in the Wi-Fi settings then, in the list under "preferred networks," you can rearrange the order of priority as to which networks you'd prefer to connect to if possible

Comment: Just in case, the wifi settings are in System Preferences > Network.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me a lot. The problem is that there wifi is public so when you wake your computer it connects to the public wifi first. You can edit the wifi-settings and can even block this wifi connection if you want in Network settings.